# Redirecting CMD window output into RichTextWindow

Tags: c#, arduino, richtextbox

I am writing a C# winform app to run and control several Arduinos. The Arduinos are programmed on the fly so I can use the same Duino to do many tasks depending on what I need to test.

Programming on the fly is easy see code below but as you can see I have to run a separate program called AVRDude and send it parameters. This is still OK but .....

AVRDude is DOS so opens up a CMD window and puts its output into that. Problem is I want that output into my Apps RichTextWindow. Searching around I find several examples and try to understand them which I seem to do but obviously I have missed a vital part which is why I ask for help.

I am trying to redirect the output from AVRDude but all I get is the empty string. What have I missed that will allow me to capture the output from AVRDude int my RichTextWindow.

My code is below:

```
private void program_duino()
    {

        var choice = cbobx_device.SelectedIndex;
        string partno = "";
        string programmer = "";
        string baudrate = "";


        switch (choice)
        {
            case 0:

                partno = "atmega2560";
                programmer = "wiring";
                baudrate = "115200";

                break;
            case 1:
                partno = "m328p";
                programmer = "arduino";
                baudrate = "115200";

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

                    using (Process sortProcess = new Process())
                    {
                        sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"avrdude.exe";
                        sortProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-Cavrdude.conf -p" + partno + " -c" + programmer + " -P" + cmbPortName.Text + " -b" + baudrate + " -D -Uflash:w:\"" + txtbx_hexfile.Text + "\":i -v";
                        sortProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


                        // Set event handler
                        sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);



                        // Start the process.
                        sortProcess.Start();

                        // Start the asynchronous read
                        sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

                        sortProcess.WaitForExit();
                    }

    }

    void SortOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Data);
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            rchtxbx_output.AppendText(e.Data ?? string.Empty);
           // Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, "\n" + (e.Data ?? string.Empty) + "\n");
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more searching and lots of trying I came up (using code from others with my alterations) with an almost 100% what I need solution. BUT .... the issue I now have is:

1. Writing back is not in real time, which means it only writes to
   Rich Text Box on completion so not in real time. Any ideas on how to
   make it write in real time?
2. I find that some of the text I need is in the Standard errors section but cannot work out why, any ideas?

Note the commented out area allows you to program duino with writing back, I just left in my code but am not using at the moment.

```
    private void program_duino()
    {

        var choice = cbobx_device.SelectedIndex;
        string partno = "";
        string programmer = "";
        string baudrate = "";


        switch (choice)
        {
            case 0:

                partno = "atmega2560";
                programmer = "wiring";
                baudrate = "115200";

                break;
            case 1:
                partno = "m328p";
                programmer = "arduino";
                baudrate = "115200";

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        // ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //  startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //  startInfo.FileName = @"avrdude.exe";
        //  startInfo.Arguments = @"-Cavrdude.conf -p" + partno + " -c" + programmer + " -P" + cmbPortName.Text + " -b" + baudrate + " -D -Uflash:w:\"" + txtbx_hexfile.Text + "\":i -v";
        //  Process.Start(startInfo);


        Process avrprog = new Process();
        StreamReader avrstdout, avrstderr;
        StreamWriter avrstdin;
        ProcessStartInfo psI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");

        psI.UseShellExecute = false;
        psI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psI.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psI.CreateNoWindow = true;

        avrprog.StartInfo = psI;
        avrprog.Start();
        avrstdin = avrprog.StandardInput;
        avrstdout = avrprog.StandardOutput;
        avrstderr = avrprog.StandardError;
        avrstdin.AutoFlush = true;

        avrstdin.WriteLine("avrdude.exe -Cavrdude.conf -p" + partno + " -c" + programmer + " -P" + cmbPortName.Text + " -b" + baudrate + " -D -Uflash:w:\"" + txtbx_hexfile.Text + "\":i -v");

        avrstdin.Close();

        Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, "\n" + (avrstdout.ReadToEnd()) + "\n");
        Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, "\n" + (avrstderr.ReadToEnd()) + "\n");// no idea why I have errors here but I write them as Incoming
   }
```